# I want to redirect my reactjs page to regular .html page?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want redirect my reactjs page to regular html page on pressing click me like link button.

Here's my code:

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
// import DoctorImg from './doctor.jpg';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
      <div>
        <Link to="/Users/yashchoksi/Documents/route/src/normal_redirect.html">Press</Link>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/Users/yashchoksi/Documents/route/src/normal_redirect.html"/>
      </Switch>
    </div>
    </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Other file is

normal_redirect.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Check this.</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>This is redirected page.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 10):

To statically link to a different page, simply use the standard HTML anchor tag:

```html
<a href="normal_redirect.html">Redirect to Html page</a>
```

When the user clicks on the link, it's a normal page navigation to the `href` value of the tag.

---

To dynamically send the user to another page, use `<Route>` component's `render` property:

```js
<Route exact path="/normal_redirect" render={() => {window.location.href="normal_redirect.html"}} />
```

Essentially, use the `Route` component's `render` property to tell the browser to navigate to a different page: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route

---

Try this:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <a href="/Users/yashchoksi/Documents/route/src/normal_redirect.html">Press</a>
      </div>);
  }
}
```

Please notice how I've removed the `Router`, `Route`, `Switch`, and `Link` components from the code. For a normal link, you don't need any of them.

Comment: Please check out the updated answer and try the second suggestion.

Comment: Do you want me to add both of the answer?

Comment: No, how do you want the user to navigate to a different url? If you want the user to click on a link and navigate, then use `<a href...>`. Otherwise, in case of dynamic navigation, use the `<Route>` component and its `render` property.

Comment: I want the user to click on link and navigate, and in respect of that I tried your first answer but it updates url but not content of page!

Comment: I can put screenshot if you required.

Answer (score 5):

Your HTML must be in your public folder, in my case `terminos.html`

1. In your `App.js`, add this code:

```
    <Route exact path="/terminos" render={() => {window.location.href="terminos.html"}} />
```

2. If you want to add an anchor, like `<a/>`, add this code:

```
     <a target="_blank" href={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "terminos.html"} > terminos</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

As the `render` property is not available in React Router v5.1 (and v6), you can have a element that does the redirection:

```
const RedirectSite = () => {
  window.location.href = "/mypage.html";
  return <></>;
};
```

And then use it like this:

```
<Route path="/" element={<RedirectSite />} />
```

Reference: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v5