# Rendering static page (javascript + html) response from API in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a way to render an html + javascript response from an API in React?

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71828419/rendering-html-response-from-api-in-react) I can render html with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML={html}`. My problem is the html response from the API also contains javascript as it is a vega visualisation.

[Placing my whole static page into public](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48898446/4755832) as a file works with `<a href="vega_example.html">Redirect to Html page</a>`. The disadvantage of this redirect is that I don't want to save a file for every API response.

Is there a way I can render a string as a static html page with React without saving it in a file?

`App.js` to render static page using the `public` file in public folder

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function MyComponent() {
    
  const [html, setHTML] = useState({__html: ""});

  useEffect(() => {
    async function createMarkup() {
      const backendHtmlString = `<a href="vega_example.html">Redirect to Html page</a>`

       console.log(backendHtmlString)
        return {__html: backendHtmlString};
     }
     
     createMarkup().then(result => setHTML(result));
  }, []);

  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={html} />;
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <MyComponent/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In `public` I have `vega_example.html` which is pretty much my API response

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega@5.22.0"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-lite@5.2.0"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-embed@6.20.8"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="vis"/>
  <script>
    const spec = {
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "A simple bar chart with embedded data.",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"a": "A", "b": 28},
      {"a": "B", "b": 55},
      {"a": "C", "b": 43},
      {"a": "D", "b": 91},
      {"a": "E", "b": 81},
      {"a": "F", "b": 53},
      {"a": "G", "b": 19},
      {"a": "H", "b": 87},
      {"a": "I", "b": 52}
    ]
  },
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "a", "type": "nominal", "axis": {"labelAngle": 0}},
    "y": {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative"}
  },
  "config": {}
};
    vegaEmbed("#vis", spec, {mode: "vega-lite"}).then(console.log).catch(console.warn);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your literal question, you could either:

- Render the content to an [iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16557787/426858) (the rendering being done by JavaScript calls, not React calls)
- (Would strongly recommend against) Use RegEx to extract the contents of `<script/>` and use [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) to run that JavaScript

However, I would instead recommend either:

- Assuming the API only serves the JSON data, render the `#vis` element with React, load the JSON data in the hook, and then run `vegaEmbed` directly at the end of the hook.
- If the API is dynamic, simply link to the API directly and let it serve the HTML dynamically instead of saving it as a file.